# Spark Dataframe Write to Postgres Column Name in Double Quotes

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, rdbms

I am trying to write a Dataframe into Postgres, where the column names in the Dataframe are codes in UPPERCASE. But the table in Postgres has column names in lowercase. When the

```
dataframe.write.jdbc -> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO xxxxxxxx ("USE_CASE_ID","CUSTOMER_CODE","HOLDOUT","REFERENCE_ID","TAG_FIELDS","COMMS_RUN_ID","PRIMARY_OFFER_ID") VALUES

ERROR: column "USE_CASE_ID" of relation "xxxxxxxx" does not exist
```

How can I make this work for any database in the future. I am not sure why Spark SQL puts "" for column names?

Another problem is, for unit testing I used H2 database, which expects the column names to be in UPPERCASE. So i ll have to satisfy for multiple databases.

Comment: What is the actual Spark code you're using to try to write the `DataFrame` into Postgres? Also, what are the contents and the schema of the `DataFrame` (you can see this using `df.show(false)` and `df.printSchema()` where `df` is the `DataFrame`). Also, please note that unit tests should not include dependencies such as databases -- the data should be mocked.

Comment: Eh, if your unit tests are approaching automated integration tests, then I think using an in memory database like H2 is ok. 

It also helps you make sure that your database code isn't too closely coupled to a particular db engine.

Comment: Yes, I am using the H2 only for unit test. When I create the tables in H2 and Postgres with lower case letters in CREATE STATEMENT, H2 converts to UPPER CASE whereas Posgres retains lowercase letters. The problem is, when I say, "inputDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(prop.getProperty("meta.db.url"), tableName, dbProperties)", the create statement generated by Spark code (batch insert is) - INSERT INTO xxxxxxxx ("USE_CASE_ID","CUSTOMER_CODE","HOLDOUT","REFERENCE_ID","TAG_FIELDS","COMMS_RUN_ID","PRIMARY_OFFER_ID") VALUES.. because I used CAPITAL letters in df.select(). its kind of Catch 22